# Fprintf bizarre output on Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, printf, stdio

I'm trying to write a function that prints the local time plus the given string, and appends a newline character at the end for readability.

Thats the current code:

```
void errLog(const std::string errorString)
{
    FILE* errorLog;
    fopen_s(&errorLog, "ErrorLog.txt", "ab+");
    time_t rawTime;
    time (&rawTime);
    struct tm errorTime;
    localtime_s(&errorTime, &rawTime);
    char timeString[20];
    strftime(timeString, 20, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &errorTime);
    fprintf(errorLog, "%s Error: %s\n", timeString, errorString);
    fclose(errorLog);
}
```

The output is the one I was expecting on Release mode. On the working program ErrorLog.txt has this new line, as intended:

```
16-09-2014 10:58:45 Error: devFont.ttf load failed
```

But on debug mode, the output seems to have taken a random string. These are two consecutive outputs, random without apparent explanation to me:

```
16-09-2014 11:13:57 Error: ΘυB
16-09-2014 11:14:09 Error: Μϊ;
```

The function is given a hard-coded string on call, so the input of errLog is exactly the same.

Comment: Might be some memory leak or memory corruption *elsewhere*.

Comment: try errorString.c_str() in fprintf call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `c_str()` to access the character pointer to pass to fprintf:

```
fprintf(errorLog, "%s Error: %s\n", timeString, errorString.c_str());
```

It's also generally more efficient in most cases to accept your parameter as a const reference `const std::string& errorString` than to force construction of a new string for the parameter when it may not be required.

Comment: It worked. The string is created (hardcoded) at the time the function is called, so wouldn't it be a waste of time to create a string and a pointer to it for a string that only exists as input to the function?Could you elaborate on why it worked on Release, please? As you can see I'm not exactly confident in c++ and/or VS12.

Comment: No idea. Could be just plain old luck that the address passed on the stack happened to co-incide with the address in memory of the character data.